# Versioning and development process setup for php + mysql with atlassian helpers

Tags: php, git, process, hudson, phpcodesniffer

I have been researching a bit to try and configure a good development and release process for a 20+ strength development team with multi project responsibilities.

I wanted to go with GIT as the versioning system since it is easy to use, setup, backup and what not. I tried to read through several guides of svn and i realized well i dont have the time to setup a complicated process. I was able to find git client support on both linux and windows and thus was happy with that.

Now to enable multi project authentication and access i started using gitosis on top of git and was able to get the functionality i needed.

Now i am looking to setup pre-commit specifically server hooks, to make sure my developers follows phpcs thoroughly and i dont want them to checkin if they dont. Now is where GIT is giving me problems. Does there exist a server side pre-commit hook detection for GIT ? I looked around but people are using SVN when this need arose. Later maybe i would like to configure similar hooks for both jabascript and css since we are using them extensively, and i found something similar to phpcs going by the name of Squiz. I hope to use that.

Also i am looking for setting up hudson to integrate with JIRA and GIT to setup both builds and iterations for each project. Are there are pitfalls to look for here or this setup with not work ?  If this works could i be pointed to some document where i can see how it will work for me?

Answer (score 0):

No there are no pre-commit hooks that reside on the server, since you never commit remotely, you always commit locally. However, you could have hooks on the server that runs when people try to push code to it.

[Spotify](http://www.spotify.com) uses hudson, jira and git in their development process and it seems to be a successful combination. If you like code reviews you can also attach Gerrit.

Comment: Would i be able to use phpcs and something like squiz on the push hooks on the server ? If my push consists of many commits will it recognize them and get all the files together before running the hook ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with either phpcs nor squiz. It depends on what you need to do when the hook(s) are executed. Not sure what you mean by "get the files together". There are different hooks that can be executed when something is pushed to a repository (pre-receive, update, post-receive, post-update). Each of them handles different things. I'm guessing you want the update hook, since you can use that one to prevent code from being pushed to a certain branch (it's executed for each ref being updated with the push)